# Updating AWS Glue Catalog Table Column Schema with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I'm attempting to modify the column schema of an AWS Glue Catalog table using Terraform.

Firstly, I created a crawler to generate the table:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "my_crawler" {

    database_name = "test_db"
    name = "test_crawler"
    role = "test_role"
    table_prefix = "test_"
    dynamic "s3_targets" {
        for_each = [
            {
                path = "s3://some_bucket/path/to/table/"
                exclusions = ["**/temp/**"]
            },
            {
                path = "s3://some_bucket/path/to/table/"
                exclusions = ["**/temp/**"]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    schema_change_policy {
        delete_behaviou = "DELETE_FROM_DATABASE"
    }
    
    configuration = jsonencode({
        "Version": 1.0,
        "Grouping": {
            "TableLevelConfiguration": 5,
            "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas"
        },
        "CrawlerOutput": {
            "Partitions": {
                "AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

After manually running the crawler, it created two catalog tables: `test_demo1` and `test_demo2`, each with 3-5 columns and 2-3 partitions.

Now, I want to reduce the structure complexity by updating the schema. I created a Terraform resource for the table:

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "my_table" {

    database_name = "test_db"
    name = "test_table"
    
    storage_descriptor {
        columns {
            name = "info"
            type = "struct<somethingA:struct<infoA:string,infoB:string>>"
            comment = "infoA and infoB"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Upon running `terraform apply`, I encountered an error: `AlreadyExistsException: Table already exists`. To resolve this, I used the `terraform import` command:

```
Terraform import aws_glue_catalog_table.my_table 123465789:test_db:test_demo1
```

Here, `123456789` is the `catalog_id`. However, subsequent `terraform apply` commands resulted in the loss of partitions and other necessary information.

How can I update only the AWS Glue Catalog table columns without removing any partitions or other information? I aim to achieve this programmatically to replicate changes across numerous tables efficiently.

Note: Manually updating the column type in the AWS console requires running the crawler again to synchronize the schema in partitions, and I want to automate this process with Terraform for multiple tables with recurring schema changes.

Edit:
I found out this can't be done. so after creating the crawler from terraform I running python script to update the schema using boto3 package.
I am running the python script after crawlers run at least one time.